# How do I build sphinx (readthedocs) documentation for Google App Engine projects?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-sphinx, read-the-docs

I have a Google App Engine project named [gaend](https://github.com/samedhi/gaend). I am attempting to build better documentation for it using [readthedocs](http://gaend.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). I have used

```
> sphinx-quickstart
```

to build my base sphinx project. Followed by

```
> sphinx-apidoc -o . ../gaend
```

to generate a API list of the project. I then run

```
sphinx-autobuild . _build/html

+--------- manually triggered build ---------------------------------------------
| Running Sphinx v1.5.2
| loading pickled environment... done
| building [mo]: targets for 0 po files that are out of date
| building [html]: targets for 0 source files that are out of date
| updating environment: 0 added, 1 changed, 0 removed
| reading sources... [100%] gaend
/Users/stephen/gaend/docs/gaend.rst:10: WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module u'gaend.bigquery'; the following exception was raised:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/stephen/.virtualenvs/gaend/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sphinx/ext/autodoc.py", line 551, in import_object
__import__(self.modname)
File "/Users/stephen/gaend/gaend/bigquery.py", line 1, in <module>
   from google.cloud import bigquery
ImportError: No module named google.cloud
...
ImportError: No module named google.appengine.ext
```

I recognize that the problem is that it does not have access to the Google Cloud SDK. I have had similar issues with running my unit test, and the work around to doing this is in [runner.py](https://github.com/samedhi/gaend/blob/master/runner.py). However, this relies on having the Google Cloud SDK (with the Python Google App Engine module installed) somewhere on my system. How am I going to get the Google Cloud SDK (and Python GAE) on the [readthedocs](https://readthedocs.org/) server that build my documentation?

Answer (score 1):

I was the same problem, I don't remember where I found the solution and maybe don't fix your problem but I solved mine adding the path of `google_appengine` folder and `google_appengine/lib/yam/lib` folder in `conf.py` file in your source folder inside of Sphinx doc folder, something like this:

In `conf.py`:

```
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../../'))
sys.path.insert(1, '<your local full path>/google_appengine')
sys.path.insert(1, '<your local full path>/google_appengine/lib/yaml/lib')

if 'google' in sys.modules:
    del sys.modules['google']
```

I know that it would be better with relative path but it worked for me.

That Sphinx need run the program that you are documenting is something that I don't understand fine but anyway, is a good tool.

Comment: Thanks Juan, I did https://github.com/samedhi/gaend/commit/d279e0ada41c2225b23498a6bb7ddba94ae624e5 . Works locally, but of course fails when readthedocs tries to build my docs on their server... Maybe I am missing a step or something?

Answer (score 0):

I just solved the same issue. There are not many questions asking about Sphinx + GAE, so I'm posting the `conf.py` code that got it working for me in the hopes it helps others:

```
import os
import sys
project_id = 'gae-project-id'
# environment variables that several utils are assuming are present
if not os.environ.get('SERVER_SOFTWARE', None):
    os.environ['SERVER_SOFTWARE'] = 'Development-'+project_id
if not os.environ.get('APPLICATION_ID', None):
    os.environ['APPLICATION_ID'] = 'dev~'+project_id
# project root
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.dirname(__file__))
# downloaded third party libs
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.dirname(__file__)+"/lib")
# path to gae sdk
sdk_path = os.path.join('~/google-cloud-sdk', 'platform/google_appengine')
try:
    import google
    google.__path__.append("{0}/google".format(sdk_path))
except ImportError:
    pass
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.expanduser(sdk_path))
import dev_appserver
dev_appserver.fix_sys_path()
```